# How to upgrade fonts in Windows [10]?

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I am using Windows 10 on 2 computers and on both of the computers i am CorelDraw (latest version) installed and when i save a file from one of the computers and then open it on the other CorelDraw is't giving me an warning that all of the fonts on the computer that i am trying to open the file are older versions. I am attaching an image to see the dialog i am getting [image: font upgrade warning]

But how can i upgrade font on windows 10 i have no clue.

Comment: Probably the one with the older fonts versions is an older Windows 10 build.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, both are Windows 10 Pro, build: 1803. so i guess this is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it's clear that the fonts on the left are older versions,
so you need to replace them by the newer fonts.

To do that:

- On the computer with the newer font, open *Control Panel > Fonts*
- Select the fonts in question
- Right-click one of then and choose *Copy*
- Position Explorer to some folder (preferably empty) and type
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Bring the files over to the other computer
- Open *Control Panel > Fonts*
- Select the font files in Explorer
- Drag and drop into the Fonts window.

Comment: i did that before i post a question here, but i still get the same error and when i go to control panel->fonts and go for example to the Times New Roman Bold font and double click on it i get `version 7.0` but when i try to open the document i get that the version of this font is 6.98. Hm...

Comment: Did you re-create the document after transferring the fonts to the computer? It might be a CorelDRAW problem - is the same version installed on both computers?